# What followed findings of A. Lenstra et al. concerning shared factors of practical RSA moduli?

Tags: rsa

A. Lenstra et al. had a paper in 2012 "Ron was wrong, Whit is right", in which one reads: "What surprised us most is that many thousands of 1024-bit RSA moduli, including thousands that are contained in still-valid X.509 certificates, offer no security at all." Has that surprise been satisfactorily explained in the meantime? I'll be particularly interested in cases where the moduli had shared factors. I mean that seems to indicate a fairly high probability that back doors could have been involved in the software that generated such moduli.

Comment: Related article: Daniel J. Bernstein, Nadia Heninger, Tanja Lange: [_The state of factoring algorithms and other cryptanalytic threats to RSA_](http://cr.yp.to/talks/2013.01.07/slides.pdf#page=18) (January 2013), pages 12-25. In particular, they state: _Vast majority of compromised keys generated by headless or embedded network devices_.